# MongoDB Aggregation. Check if nested array contains value

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have such fields in entity:

```
private String userId;
private String username;
private Date created;
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

`Comment` have such fields :

```
private String userId;
private String username;
private String message;
private Date created;
```

I need to make aggregation, and receive something like this :

```
{
  "userId" : "%some_userId%",
  "date" : "%some_date%",
  "commentsQty" : 100,
  "isCommented" : true
}
```

My aggregation looks like this:

```
{ "aggregate" : "%entityName%" , "pipeline" : [
   { "$project" : { 
              "username" : 1 , 
              "userId" : 1 , 
              "created" : 1 , 
              "commentQty" : { "$size" : [ "$comments"]}}}]}
```

And it's working fine. But i need also to check, IF comments array contains some comment, with specific userId. I tried this one, but it fails to execute:

```
{ "aggregate" : "%entityName%" , "pipeline" : [
   { "$project" : { 
              "username" : 1 , 
              "userId" : 1 ,
              "created" : 1 , 
              "commentQty" : { "$size" : [ "$comments"]} ,
              "isCommented" : { "$exists" : [ "$comments.userId" , "5475b1e45409e07b0da09235"]}}}]}
```

with such message : `Command execution failed:  Error [exception: invalid operator '$exists']`

How such check can be done?

**UPD:** Also tried operators `$in` and similar, but they valid for queering, not for aggregation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *with such message : Command execution failed: Error [exception: invalid operator '$exists']*

Currently the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator is not available in the `aggregation` pipeline.

**edit:**

Writing up a better answer:

You could check if any user has commented, by:

- using [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator to get an array with the `userId` we are looking for, if the user has really commented on the post.
- apply [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator to get the size of the resultant array.
- use [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) operator to check if the size is greater than `0`.
- if it is, it means there exists one or more comments by the `userId` we are looking for, else not.

sample code:

```
var userIdToQuery = "2";
var userIdsToMatchAgainstComments = [ObjectId("5475b1e45409e07b0da09235")];

db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"userId":userIdToQuery}},
{$project:{"userName":1,
           "created":1,
           "commentQty":{$size:"$comments"},
           "isCommented":{$cond:
                          [{$gt:[
                           {$size:
                             {$setIntersection:["$comments.userId",
                                     userIdsToMatchAgainstComments]}}
                          ,0]},
                          true,false]}}}
])
```

**previous answer:**

- `Unwind` comments.
- `Project` an extra field `isCommented` For each comments document,
  check if it has the `userId` that we are searching for, if it has the
  corresponding `userId`, then set the variable to `1` else `0`.
- `Group` together the documents again, sum the value in `isCommented`, if
  it is `> 0`, the document with the user id is present in the group else
  not.
- `Project` the fields accordingly.

The Code:

```
{ "aggregate" : "%entityName%" , "pipeline" :[
    {$unwind:"$comments"},
    {$project:{
               "username":1,
               "userId":1,
               "created":1,
               "comments":1,
               "isCommented":{$cond:[{$eq:["$comments.userId",
                                           ObjectId("5475b1e45409e07b0da09235")
                                          ]
                                     },
                                     1,
                                     0]}}},
    {$group:{"_id":{"_id":"$_id",
                    "username":"$username",
                    "userId":"$userId",
                    "created":"$created"},
             "isCommented":{$sum:"$isCommented"},
             "commentsArr":{$push:"$comments"}}},
    {$project:{"comments":"$commentsArr",
               "_id":0,
               "username":"$_id.username",
               "userId":"$_id.userId",
               "created":"$_id.userId",
               "isCommented":{$cond:[{$eq:["$isCommented",0]},
                                  false,
                                  true]},
               "commentQty":{$size:"$commentsArr"}}},
    ]}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But seems that this not what i need. I need to check if array CONTAINS specific value. In my case i need to check, if "$comments" array contains comment with userId, say, "5475b1e45409e07b0da09235".

Comment: I mean, isCommented field, it's - is commented by ME, mean, current user. So i need to check it during aggregation to avoid one more request to mongo...

Comment: Check my updated answer. So the comments- userId will have the ObjectId of the corresponding user?

Comment: I finally implemented this in java code. Your solution is correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3211705 - Thanks for the comments, triggering a writeup for a better answer. It is definitely possible. Have updated my answer with a better approach.

Comment: I think $cond is redundant, $gt returns boolean by it's own

Comment: @BatScream Btw thanks for the answer, I tried to do something similar without any luck for few hours, $setIntersection always returned empty array. Finally found out the reason, userId was stored as ObjectId and I compared it with a String. You answer helped me instantly haha

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check for an exact single value (i.e. a specific logged-in *userId*), simply use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator:

```
let loggedInUserId = "user1";

db.entities.aggregate([
{$project:{
    "userName": 1,
    "isCommentedByLoggedInUser": {
        $in : [ loggedInUserId, "$comments.userId" ]
    },
])
```

That's it.

Beware: If you don't expect every document to have *comments* array, wrap it with the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator, and yield an empty array:

```
$in : [ loggedInUserId, { "$ifNull": [ "$comments.userId", [] ] } ]
```

---

BatScream's awesome answer is for checking against multiple values, when you need at least one out of many users (*any* logic) to fulfill the requirement. It is not required for your situation, as I see it, but it is a nice way of doing it.

So, BatScream mentioned the *any* logic, in the aggregational-way, and I'll continue with the *all* logic in the aggregational-way. For finding documents that have *all* specific users' comments, simply use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator:

```
let manyUsersIdsThatWeWantAll = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];

db.entities.aggregate([
{$project:{
    "userName": 1,
    "isCommentedByAllThoseUsers": {
        $setIsSubset: [
            manyUsersIdsThatWeWantAll, // the needle set MUST be the first expression
            "$comments.userId"
        ]
    },
])
```